# How to sort a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, sorting

What is the best way of creating an alphabetically sorted list in Python?

Comment: Use `locale` and it's string collation methods to sort naturally according to current locale.

Answer (score 582, accepted):

Basic answer:

```
mylist = ["b", "C", "A"]
mylist.sort()
```

This modifies your original list (i.e. sorts in-place). To get a sorted copy of the list, without changing the original, use the [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) function:

```
for x in sorted(mylist):
    print x
```

However, the examples above are a bit naive, because they don't take locale into account, and perform a case-sensitive sorting. You can take advantage of the optional parameter `key` to specify custom sorting order (the alternative, using `cmp`, is a deprecated solution, as it has to be evaluated multiple times - `key` is only computed once per element).

So, to sort according to the current locale, taking language-specific rules into account ([`cmp_to_key`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) is a helper function from functools):

```
sorted(mylist, key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll))
```

And finally, if you need, you can specify a [custom locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) for sorting:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8') # vary depending on your lang/locale
assert sorted((u'Ab', u'ad', u'aa'),
  key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)) == [u'aa', u'Ab', u'ad']
```

Last note: you will see examples of case-insensitive sorting which use the `lower()` method - those are incorrect, because they work only for the ASCII subset of characters. Those two are wrong for any non-English data:

```
# this is incorrect!
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x.lower())
# alternative notation, a bit faster, but still wrong
mylist.sort(key=str.lower)
```

Comment: `mylist.sort(key=str.lower)` is faster.

Comment: Good point.  I'll leave my current example as-is, since it's probably easier for a beginner to see what's happening, but I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: If anyone is curious, performance of list.sort() can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method)

Comment: How does this `mylist.sort(key=str.lower)` work? What is the name of this function passing construct?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `str.lower` will not sort correctly for non-ASCII characters, let this example: `['a', 'b', 'â']`

Comment: @BornToCode : 1- [I know](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446833). Look at the revision (2008) my comment replies to (my comment is about the unnecessary use of  lambda). 2- sorting non-ASCII characters is a big separate topic. [PyICU could be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11124645) instead of the locale-based solution.

Comment: I can't believe it but it doesn't work: `print([1, 2, 3].sort())` returns `None`!

Comment: @Dmitry This is because you are printing the return value of the sort function called in `[1, 2, 3].sort()`.  As `sort()` sorts the list in place (ie, changes the list directly), it doesn't return the sorted list, and actually doesn't return anything, so your print statement prints `None`.  If you saved your list to a variable, say `x`, called `x.sort()`, then `print(x)`, you would see the sorted list.

Answer (score 62):

It is also worth noting the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function:

```
for x in sorted(list):
    print x
```

This returns a new, sorted version of a list without changing the original list.

Answer (score 40):

```
list.sort()
```

It really is that simple :)

Comment: In general, it is surprisingly far from simple. But ok, the simplest case is actually simple.

Answer (score 19):

The proper way to sort strings is:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8') # vary depending on your lang/locale
assert sorted((u'Ab', u'ad', u'aa'), cmp=locale.strcoll) == [u'aa', u'Ab', u'ad']

# Without using locale.strcoll you get:
assert sorted((u'Ab', u'ad', u'aa')) == [u'Ab', u'aa', u'ad']
```

The previous example of `mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x.lower())` will work fine for ASCII-only contexts.

Answer (score 18):

Please use sorted() function in Python3

```
items = ["love", "like", "play", "cool", "my"]
sorted(items2)
```

Answer (score 8):

> But how does this handle language specific sorting rules? Does it take locale into account?

No, `list.sort()` is a generic sorting function. If you want to sort according to the Unicode rules, you'll have to define a custom sort key function. You can try using the [pyuca](http://jtauber.com/blog/2006/01/27/python_unicode_collation_algorithm/) module, but I don't know how complete it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
l =['abc' , 'cd' , 'xy' , 'ba' , 'dc']
l.sort()
print(l)
```

Result

> ['abc', 'ba', 'cd', 'dc', 'xy']

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but if you want to do **locale-aware sorting without setting** `locale.LC_ALL` you can do so by using the [PyICU library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU) as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124645/1879728):

```py
import icu # PyICU

def sorted_strings(strings, locale=None):
    if locale is None:
       return sorted(strings)
    collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(locale))
    return sorted(strings, key=collator.getSortKey)
```

Then call with e.g.:

```py
new_list = sorted_strings(list_of_strings, "de_DE.utf8")
```

This worked for me without installing any locales or changing other system settings.

(This was already suggested [in a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings#comment62733021_36156), but I wanted to give it more prominence, because I missed it myself at first.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `s = "ZWzaAd"`

To sort above string the simple solution will be below one.

```
print ''.join(sorted(s))
```

Comment: that is not a list of strings you are sorting here

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe:

```
names = ['Jasmine', 'Alberto', 'Ross', 'dig-dog']
print ("The solution for this is about this names being sorted:",sorted(names, key=lambda name:name.lower()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:
https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/5db81676e4

```
scores = '54 - Alice,35 - Bob,27 - Carol,27 - Chuck,05 - Craig,30 - Dan,27 - Erin,77 - Eve,14 - Fay,20 - Frank,48 - Grace,61 - Heidi,03 - Judy,28 - Mallory,05 - Olivia,44 - Oscar,34 - Peggy,30 - Sybil,82 - Trent,75 - Trudy,92 - Victor,37 - Walter'
```

scores = scores.split(',')
for x in sorted(scores):
  print(x)