# What algorithm does Python's built-in sort() method use?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, python-internals

What algorithm is the built in `sort()` method in Python using? Is it possible to have a look at the code for that method?

Comment: Of course it's possible to look at the code for the method - Python is an open-source project. The method is probably implemented in C, however, so you'll have to know a bit about C to make any sense of it.

Comment: Does the version matter?

Comment: @melder: No =) I just want to have a look at a pro algorithm :P
@chris: how?

Comment: Download the source code to the Python interpreter. I don't know where they implement the `sort()` method, or what the formatting to the interpreter is, but it's got to be in there somewhere, and I bet it's implemented in C for speed concerns.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python) is an example of it being used

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Sure!  The code's [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c), starting with function `islt` and proceeding for QUITE a while;-). As Chris's comment suggests, it's C code.  You'll also want to read [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listsort.txt) text file for a textual explanation, results, etc etc.

If you prefer reading Java code than C code, you could look at Joshua Bloch's implementation of timsort in and for Java (Joshua's also the guy who implemented, in 1997, the modified mergesort that's still used in Java, and one can hope that Java will eventually switch to his recent port of timsort).

Some explanation of the Java port of timsort is [here](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view%5Fbug.do?bug%5Fid=6804124), the diff is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/jdk/rev/bfd7abda8f79) (with pointers to all needed files), the key file is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/jdk/file/bfd7abda8f79/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) -- FWIW, while I'm a better C programmer than Java programmer, in this case I find Joshua's Java code more readable overall than Tim's C code;-).

Comment: @Chris, "Browse Python sources" is a shortcut in all of my browsers' bookmark bars -- it points to http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/ ;-).

Comment: I want to know what the function `list_ass_item()` does. :)

Comment: Performs assignment to an item of the list (just like list_ass_slice performs assignment to a slice of the list), nothing to do with sorting. I guess the abbreviation of "assignment" makes the name funny...

Comment: [The current version](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/listsort.txt) of `listsort.txt` adds some notes that address common confusions.

Comment: What are the theoretical time and space complexities of timsort?

Answer (score 12):

In early versions of Python, the `sort` function implemented a modified version of quicksort. However, in 2.3 this was replaced with an adaptive mergesort algorithm, in order to provide a [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) sort by default.

Comment: quicksort isn't 'deemed unstable' - by the commonly used definitions, quicksort is unstable - that is the original ordering of two objects is not preserved, if they are equal during this sort. Having an unstable sort algorithm means that you have to come up with all sorts of 'magic' to sensibly sort data with multiple criteria, rather than then simply being able to chain sort calls - in timsort if you want to sort by D.O.B and then name, you simply sort by name first, and then D.O.B. You can't do that with quicksort

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I think the author of this answer may have, at the time, been reading the documentation and misunderstood "stable" as referring to software quality - rather than to a property of sorting algorithms. I edited the answer so that it is clear about the meaning, and added a reference link for that concept.

Answer (score 2):

Since python version 3.11, `sort()` now uses a version of [powersort](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/storage/00lipics/lipics-vol112-esa2018/LIPIcs.ESA.2018.63/LIPIcs.ESA.2018.63.pdf), a merge-sort algorithm that takes advantage of runs: sequences of already-sorted values in the data. When the length is less than 64, python switches to binary insertion sort.

python implementation details: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listsort.txt