# Variation of the counting sort algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I realize this isn't the standard counting sort as stated in CLRS, but what does my simplified version lack that the standard counting sort has? I realize mine only sorts positive integers, but that should be pretty easy to tweak (by using maps).

```
def count_sort(array):
    maximum = max(array)
    minimum = min(0, min(array))
    count_array = [0]*(maximum-minimum+1)

    for val in array:
        count_array[val] += 1

    sorted_array = []
    for i in range(minimum, maximum+1):
        if count_array[i] > 0:
            for j in range(0, count_array[i]):
                sorted_array.append(i)

    return sorted_array

array = [3,2,-1,1,5,0,10,18,25,25]
print array
print count_sort(array)
```

**Edit:** The reason why I thought this wasn't the standard counting sort was because the algorithm covered in the MIT OpenCourseware lecture seemed slightly more involved (http://youtu.be/0VqawRl3Xzs?t=34m54s).

Comment: What makes you think this isn't counting sort?  This looks perfectly valid to me.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a problem either. FWIW, you shouldn't even need maps to handle negative numbers - just create a big enough `count_array` to hold them all, and let the negative indices wrap around.

Comment: There's a particular reason for not using the built-in `max()`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. See my edit above for why I thought this wasn't the standard counting sort. @RikPoggi - I'm new to Python; max(array) seems much better, thanks! I've tweaked the original code.

Comment: This answer has a pythonic way of removing your inner for loop (see how result is extended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775963/what-is-an-on-algorithm-to-pair-two-equally-lengthed-lists-in-order-in-place/8776258#8776258

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something odd with your min and max. Try this:

```
def count_sort(array):
    maximum = max(array)
    minimum = min(array)
    count_array = [0]*(maximum-minimum+1)

    for val in array:
        count_array[val-minimum] += 1

    sorted_array = []
    for i in range(minimum, maximum+1):
        if count_array[i-minimum] > 0:
            for j in range(0, count_array[i-minimum]):
                sorted_array.append(i)

    print sorted_array

array = [3,2,-1,1,5,0,10,18,25,25]
print array
count_sort(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see problems with the way you're count-sorting, anyway some suggestions to your code come to mind that maybe can interest you.

For example the line:

```
minimum = min(0, min(array))
```

could be replaced with:

```
minimum = min(0, *array)
```

If you ran your code in python-2.x use [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range), so you could change:

```
for i in range(minimum, maximum+1):
```

with:

```
for i in xrange(minimum, maximum+1):
```

For the last loop you don't actually need `range()` at all, check out the question [pythonic way to do something N times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2970780/1132524), so you could change:

```
for j in range(0, count_array[i]):
    sorted_array.append(i)
```

with:

```
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, count_array[i]):
    sorted_array.append(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort ?

If yes, it's almost similar to your code. But it has one improvement: "The relative order of items with equal keys is preserved here, i.e. this is a stable sort.". So if you are sorting key-value dictionary order of the values will remain the same if they have equal keys.

Comment: No, it is not stable. The created array does not contain copies of the initial elements but it is created using the `i` index.

Comment: Can you explain? That phrase in the quotes was simply copied from the wiki. I suppose the author meant that stable sort is the sort that preserves order in items with equal keys. Maybe that word isn't used well here, but anyway it's clear from the sentence before it, what does it mean

Comment: Well, in the algorithm above the integers are sorted. On wikipedia, items linked to keys are.

Comment: Yep, when you are sorting just integers it doesn't matter. But in general when you are talking about sort problem it means that all integers could be used as a keys, so you need to sort the data with keys, but not the keys alone. The sorting algorithms in real life are used mostly to sort dictionaries, not just lists. Also you can what  read what means stability (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) in the sorting algorithms. Sorry for providing wiki links, if you think that wiki isn't truthly enough - you can view links in the bottom of the wiki page.