# What algorithm does python's sorted() use?

Tags: python, sorting

In Python 2.7, how does Python's built-in `sorted` function work - what algorithm does it use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method Question has been answered here. It uses Timsort

Comment: For others who are curious, this article is great: http://corte.si//posts/code/timsort/index.html

Comment: @HartleyBrody, the link is broken. Are you referring to https://corte.si/posts/code/timsort/ or https://corte.si/posts/code/timsort-grayscale/ ?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Older versions of Python (2.3 - 3.10) used an algorithm called [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort):

> **Timsort is a hybrid sorting algorithm, derived from merge sort and
> insertion sort, designed to perform well on many kinds of real-world
> data.** It was invented by Tim Peters in 2002 for use in the Python
> programming language. The algorithm finds subsets of the data that are
> already ordered, and uses the subsets to sort the data more
> efficiently. This is done by merging an identified subset, called a
> run, with existing runs until certain criteria are fulfilled. **Timsort was Python's standard sorting algorithm from version 2.3 to version 3.10.** It is
> now also used to sort arrays in Java SE 7, and on the Android
> platform.

Since 3.11, Python uses [Powersort](https://www.wild-inter.net/publications/munro-wild-2018), which was designed by Ian Munro and Sebastian Wild. It is an improved nearly-optimal mergesort that adapts to existing runs of sorted data.

Comment: It's a very impressive algorithm: the OP's friend would be very hard-pressed to develop something better on their own.

Comment: Not only does it use an extremely clever algorithm, is also implements it in hand-optimized C. Even if you implemented it yourself by translating the pseudocode into Python, it would be an order of magnitude slower and more memory-hungry.

Comment: An interesting paper says that it's found a bug in TimSort (and provides a fix for it): http://envisage-project.eu/proving-android-java-and-python-sorting-algorithm-is-broken-and-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: @bgporter To be precise, the bug was not in Timsort, but in its reference implementation. According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Formal_verification), it has been fixed already.

Answer (score 15):

The sort algorithm is called Timsort.  See [timsort](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Answer (score 13):

Since 2.3 Python has used timsort.

More info: http://bugs.python.org/file4451/timsort.txt