# understanding the working principle of sorted function python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have a problem with working principle of python built-in sorting function. 
I have person class and it holds two attributes such as name and number. I want to sort it based on name attributes. If two names are equal it should be sorted based on number attribute.

```
import numpy as np
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name=name
        self.number=number

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}, {}".format(self.number, self.name)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.name, self.number) < (other.name, other.number)


customList=[
    Person('object', 99),
    Person('michael', 1),
    Person('theodore', 21),
    Person('amazon', 21),
    Person('life', 42),
    Person('tree', 42)
]

a=sorted(customList)
print(a)
```

Here, I overwrites `__lt__` function. However, still it is not clear how `sorted` function uses it.

I assume that sorting might work in the following code:

```
for each element1 in arr:
    for each element2 in arr:
        compare element1 and elements with overwritten __lt__ function
```

Still, the way how sorted function works is not clear for me.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me. I have changed it.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question. Seems like you understand how `sorted` works..

Comment: In principle, your assumption is correct. Except that Python's sorting implementation is clever enough to not compare all possible pairs of items from `arr`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948920/what-algorithm-does-pythons-sorted-use