# What are the ... in built in function definitions in Python?

Tags: python, list

[image: ImageExplainingALot]

I saw these function definitions in the `list` class (although these types of definitions are everywhere)

I first thought that the `sort` function of `list` would've been a bubble or a selective sort, but its a ...!

I understand almost every other thing in these definitions, but the ... after : and in the arguements confuses me

any explainations?

Comment: "I saw these function definitions in the list class" How *exactly* did you see them? the builtins do *not* have available Python source in the reference implementation. They are *not implemented in Python* in the reference implementation.

Comment: I ctrl clicked the function `sort` in vscode, and it took me here

Comment: Then, this is a pseudo-implementation (or defintion) provided by vscode, in its own notation, and the best way to understand it is via the vscode documentation.

Comment: For the Python sort algorithm Python uses, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948920. It is neither a bubble sort nor a selection sort. It is also not a `...` because those (rather weird) notations are pseudo-type-hints for the named parameters `key=` (which specifies the sort *order*, not the *algorithm*) and `reverse=` (which is a `bool` that does what you think it does).  If you really want to know about how Python does something, go to the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html Other sources can be oversimplified, misleading, and occasionally downright wrong.