# Built in sort() method of python

Tags: python, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [About python’s built in sort() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method)

Which of the sorting algorithms does the `sort()` method use to sort a list of numbers? How can I prove it?

```
seq = list_of_numbers
seq.sort()
```

Comment: As a side note, You probably mean, "Which algorithm does cpython's `sort` method use".  A python *implementation* is free to use whatever sorting algorithm that it wants provided that the algorithm is stable.

Comment: @mgilson: Jython uses `Collections.sort()` (so presumably that's also TimSort). Looking for IronPython now..

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Timsort is good.  I suspect that they all use it.  I just wanted to point out (again) that `cpython` *is not python*.  It's an implementation and OP is asking about an *implementation detail*.

Comment: @mgilson: Yup, I know; just tickled into looking for the implementations. I can honestly say that "I was there" when Tim invented TimSort (we were working at the same company at the time), so I feel a certain affinity. :-)

Comment: @mgilson: after some distractions, found the IronPython list implementation. It uses merge sort (I am all disappointed now).

Comment: @mgilson: and pypy is using TimSort again: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/tip/pypy/rlib/listsort.py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It uses [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), an algorithm developed for Python by Tim Peters (of Zen of Python fame).

It is a hybrid of Merge and Insertion sort, and now also in use in Java and Android. The Python source code includes [a more detailed description](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listsort.txt). You'll find the implementation in the [`listobject.c` C source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f2353e74b335/Objects/listobject.c#l980).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to determine the sorting algorithm and to prove you're correct is look at the [source](http://hg.python.org).

Answer (score 0):

This may enlight you. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216689/sorting-algorithms-in-python

You can prove it by showing the c code under the hood.

This is almost your same question. [About Python's built in sort() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method)