# Python : Which Sort Method is used behind .sort()?

Tags: sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I have always heard that usually merge sort is used for in built functions. But I cannot understand why. Quicksort is faster obviously with exact time complexity of 1.39NlogN and also it is in place! then why not quick sort?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method

Comment: `Timsort` is used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort, which is *easily* found by Googling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timesort algo is used in the inbuilt sort

Comment: tim**e**sort? I think you mean timsort