# time complexity of sorting a dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

I was wondering what is the time complexity of sorting a dictionary by key and sorting a dictionary by value.

for e.g :

```
for key in sorted(my_dict, key = my_dict.get):
  <some-code>
```

in the above line , what is the time complexity of **sorted** ? If it is assumed that quicksort is used, is it O(NlogN) on an average and O(N*N) in the worst case ?

and is the time complexity of sorting by value and sorting by key are different ? Since , accessing the value by its key takes only O(1) time, both should be same ?

Thanks.

Comment: Python uses Timsort http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method

Comment: They are not  different , both of them are list with `N` members

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary, you can only sort a sequence *returned* from a dictionary. If you try to iterate it directly, you get a sequence of the keys without the values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sorted` doesn't really sort a dictionary; it collects the iterable it receives into a list and sorts the list using the [Timsort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). Timsort is decidedly *not* a variant of quicksort, it is a hybrid algorithm closer to merge sort. According to wikipedia, its complexity is O(n log n) in the worst case, with optimizations to speed up the commonly encountered partially ordered data sets.

Since collecting the dict keys and values are both O(n), the complexity of  both sorts is the same, determined by the sort algorithm as O(n log n).

Comment: Did you mean O(n log n) at the end?