# Sorting a list of python sets by value

Tags: python, sorting, hashmap, set, frozenset

The frozenset docs says:

> The frozenset type is immutable and hashable — its contents cannot be altered after it is created; it can therefore be used as a dictionary key or as an element of another set.

However, the docs for for python sets says:

> Since sets only define partial ordering (subset relationships), the output of the list.sort() method is undefined for lists of sets.

This makes me ask:  why is the case?  And, if I wanted to sort a list of sets by set content, how could I do this?  I know that the extension intbitset:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intbitset/2.3.0 , has a function for returning a bit sequence that represents the set contents.  Is there something comparable for python sets?

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you can't do and then we can provide a code example of how to do it.

Comment: Okay, so I understand this request in some cases.  But what in the world do I need a code example for here.  What is confusing about this question that a code example would clear up?  I was pretty specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python sort a list of sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956966/how-does-python-sort-a-list-of-sets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples, lists, strings, etc. have a natural lexicographic ordering and can be sorted because you can always compare two elements of a given collection. That is, either `a < b`, `b < a`, or `a == b`.

A natural comparison between two sets is having `a <= b` mean `a` is a subset of `b`, which is what the expression `a <= b` actually does in Python. What the documentation means by "partial ordering" is that not all sets are comparable. Take, for example, the following sets:

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {4, 5, 6}
```

Is `a` a subset of `b`? No. Is `b` a subset of `a`? No. Are they equal? No. If you can't compare them at all, you clearly can't sort them.

The only way you can sort a collection of sets is if your comparison function actually can compare any two elements (a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)). This means you can still sort a collection of sets using the above subset relation, but you will have to ensure that all of the sets are comparable (e.g. `[{1}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2}]`).

The easiest way to do what you want is to transform each individual set into something that you actually *can* compare. Basically, you do `f(a) <= f(b)` (where `<=` is obvious) for some simple function `f`. This is done with the `key` keyword argument:

```
In [10]: def f(some_set):
   ...       return max(some_set)
   ...

In [11]: sorted([{1, 2, 3, 999}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}], key=f)
Out[11]: [{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 999}]
```

You're sorting `[f(set1), f(set2), f(set3)]` and applying the resulting ordering to `[set1, set2, set3]`.

Answer (score 3):

Take an example: say you wanted to sort a list of sets by the "first element" of each set.  The issue is that Python sets or frozensets don't have a "first element."  They have no sense of their own ordering.  A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.

Furthermore, `list.sort()` sorts the list in place, [using only the `<` operator between items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort).

If you just use `a.sort()` without passing any `key` parameter, saying `set_a < set_b` (or `set_a.__lt__(set_b)`) is *insufficient*.  By insufficient, I mean that `set_a.__lt__(set_b)` is a *subset* operator.  (Is `a` a subset of `b`?).  As mentioned by @Blender and referenced in your question, this provides for partial rather than total ordering, which is insufficient for defining what ever sequence holds the sets.

From the docs:

> `set < other`: Test whether the set is a proper subset of other, that
>   is, `set <= other` and `set != other`.

You *could* pass a `key` to `sort()`, it just couldn't refer to anything to do with the "ordering" of the sets internally, because remember--there is none.

```
>>> a = {2, 3, 1}
>>> b = {6, 9, 0, 1}
>>> c = {0}
>>> i = [b, a, c]
>>> i.sort(key=len)
>>> i
[{0}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 9, 6, 1}]
```