# Is str.strip dysfunctionning

Tags: python, functional-programming, strip

I have a list built from a string split operation, and I wanted to input it to map() function, then strip these substrings from their trailing parenthesis and spaces.
And rebuild a list from them.

```
teststring=" (A) / (B) "
result = list(map(str.strip, teststring.split("/"), " ()"))
```

But in the end, I only strip oddly the substrings, while "all combinations are tested", as stated by docs.

I  know another method is available with list comprehension:

```
result = [substr.strip(' ()' for substr in teststring.split("/")]
```

which works.. But I wonder why map doesn't work correctly.

I am on python 3.6.4, with Anaconda 4.4 on windows64.

Subsidiary question; the following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method) gives some pointers to find source code of functions. But I could not find the code for map (and generally, for builtin functions), so I could not see if there were bugs into it...

Comment: What do you expect `map(str.strip, teststring.split("/"), " ()")` to do? When you give `map` multiple iterables it iterates over them in parallel (like `zip` does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` with 3 arguments is not behaving the way you think it does. The 3rd argument for `map` is **not** the arguments for the function provided as the 1st argument. It is used as a 2nd iterable.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> map(function, iterable, ...) Return an iterator that applies function
>   to every item of iterable, yielding the results. If additional
>   iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments
>   and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. With
>   multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is
>   exhausted. For cases where the function inputs are already arranged
>   into argument tuples, see itertools.starmap()

In other words:

`map(str.strip, teststring.split('/'), ' ()')` is **not** equivalent to

`[substr.strip(' ()' for substr in teststring.split('/')]`. It is remotely equivalent to

`[(substr_1.strip(), substr_2.strip()) for (substr_1, substr_2) in zip(teststring.split("/"), ' ()')]`

See the difference?

Comment: Thanks. I badly misunderstood the "*iterable" in the docs. I think if I did not want to use the list comprehension, I could achieve what I want with a zip and starmap, but indeed list comprehension is better.

Comment: @AndoJurai no, zip+starmap would do the equivalent of what you are doing here! I.E. `map(f, iterable1, iterable2)` is equivalent to `starmap(f, zip(iterable1, iterable2))`

Comment: I meant using something like starmap(str.strip, zip(teststring.split, repeat(" ()") ) ). starmap works when data is as tuples, but if you input " ()" each time, it is ok.

Answer (score 3):

`map` works differently from how you are using it. When you do `map(f, a, b)`, it yields `f(a[0], b[0]), f(a[1], b[1]), ...`, while you are using it like it will yield `f(a[0], b), f(a[1], b), ...`.

To fix this, you can use a list comprehension, like in the question, or a lambda like `lambda string: string.strip(" ()")`.

Comment: Of course, using `map` with a lambda like that is going to be slower than the equivalent list comp, since the list comp avoids that extra Python function call.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you seem to be under the impression that the last argument to `map` gets passed as an argument to the function being mapped, that isn't what happens, instead, from the docs:

> map(func, *iterables) --> map object
>
> Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from each
>   of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

In other words, `list(map(f, [1,2,3], 'abc'))` is the equivalent of:

```
[f(1,'a'), f(2, 'b'), f(3, 'c')]
```

Which is not what you want. You want to *partially apply* `string.strip` using `" ()"` as the second argument, but instead, `" ()"` is being take as another *iterable of arguments*. So, straightforward solution, use a helper function:

```
In [9]: def strip_stuff(s):
   ...:     return s.strip(" ()")
   ...:

In [10]: list(map(strip_stuff, teststring.split("/")))
Out[10]: ['A', 'B']
```

You could make a factor function if you will be needing to be flexible:

```
In [12]: def make_strip(stuff):
    ...:     def strip(s):
    ...:         return s.strip(stuff)
    ...:     return strip
    ...:

In [13]: list(map(make_strip(" ()"), teststring.split("/")))
Out[13]: ['A', 'B']

In [14]: list(map(make_strip("()"), teststring.split("/")))
Out[14]: [' (A) ', ' (B) ']

In [15]: list(map(make_strip(" )"), teststring.split("/")))
Out[15]: ['(A', '(B']

In [16]: list(map(make_strip(" ("), teststring.split("/")))
Out[16]: ['A)', 'B)']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `operator.methodcaller`:

```
list(map(operator.methodcaller('strip',' ()'),teststring.split("/")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lambda` function it can be achieved as follows:

```
map(lambda s: s.strip(" ()"), teststring.split("/"))
```

Comment: That's not really useful here!