# Linear Sorting of Lists with 2 Elements

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

This is my first question here so I accept any/all tips in case my question is not properly worded.

First off, the problem:

Say we have the following array A = [(1,'cat'), (1,'dog'), (0,'giraffe'), (0,'cheetah'),(1,'elephant')]

I need to use an algorithm that will sort this list based on the first element of each component (meaning the number). It is specifically mentioned that it does not have to be a stable algorithm (I guess meaning that we do not need to consider the sorting of the words after the number, just the 0s being before all the 1s)

I should also mention that I do not wish to employ the strategies of creating side-arrays that I will populate with the results as the algorithm sorts them. The requirement is for the algorithm to sort the array within the same array.

The code I have devised is the following:

```
def SwapAround(A, start, end):
start_pos = start

for i in range(start,end):
    if A[i] < A[end]:
        A[i], A[start_pos] = A[start_pos], A[i]
        start_pos = start_pos + 1
A[start_pos], A[end] = A[end], A[start_pos]

return start_pos


A=[(1,'cat'),(0,'dog'),(1,'kangaroo'),(0,'mule'),(1,'giraffe'),(1,'dog'), 
(0,'bat')]
SwapAround(A,0,len(A) - 1)
print(A)
```

I am having rather peculiar issues with it, although I am pretty confident that it should be working (at least walking down the code line by line it made good sense to me).

The code sorts the list, but not completely... for example, my most recent output was:

```
[(0, 'bat'), (0, 'dog'), (1, 'kangaroo'), (0, 'mule'), (1, 'giraffe'), (1, 'dog'), (1, 'cat')]
```

With a smaller list, it has actually worked, and I was dumbfounded to wake up this morning to add a couple more components to my list and it not working.

Could you possibly tell me if you can see something readily "wrong" that I should consider, and the rationale behind that so that I may fully comprehend it.

Second Question: If I wanted to add components to my list that had the number 2 as well (meaning my algorithm would have to sort between 0,1,2 instead of just 0 and 1) would you use a completely different algorithm or should swapping still work? My initial thought was that Swapping would not work properly (and it hasn't with this algorithm) and maybe a CountingSort or RadixSort would work better, so your input would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Two notes: the `sorted` builtin already sorts lexicographically, but I assume this is a programming exercise. You can use any sort algorithm you would find on the internet and adjust it to just look at the first element of an item to sort.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I also answered below because I feel it's my mistake that I misled you. The programming is done in Python to test/implement the algorithm, but the primary purpose is coming up with the appropriate algorithm for that purpose. I wouldn't wanna completely rip off code, not just because it wouldn't be "mine" but because I aim to comprehend it fully prior to using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is conceptually wrong, though it's already close to the solution.

The important problem with your algorithm is that only the first element to swap will ever change. Instead you need to move both the index of the last and first element.

```
def sort_binary_key(arr):
    l, u = 0, len(arr) - 1

    while l < u:
        if arr[l] == 1 and arr[u] == 0:
            arr[l], arr[u] = arr[u], arr[l]
        elif arr[l] == 1:
            u -= 1
        elif arr[u] == 0:
            l += 1
        else:
            u -= 1
            l += 1
```

For the second part of the question:
Yes, it's possible. Run the above algorithm twice. In the first run, move all elements with 0 to the lower part of the array, all other elements to the upper. Afterwards run the same algorithm over the second part of the array, sorting between elements with 1 and 2 as first tuple-member.

```
def sort_binary_key(arr, l, u, key_mapper):
    while l < u:
        al, au = key_mapper(arr[l]), key_mapper(arr[u])

        if al == 1 and au == 0:
            arr[l], arr[u] = arr[u], arr[l]
        elif al == 1:
            u -= 1
        elif au == 0:
            l += 1
        else:
            u -= 1
            l += 1

    return l

def sort_ternary(arr):
    tmp = sort_binary_key(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, lambda t: 0 if t == 0 else 1)
    sort_binary_key(arr, tmp, len(arr) - 1, lambda t: 0 if t == 1 else 1)
```

Note that the above code is only intended as a demonstration. This code works with lists of integers instead of the input provided by OP.

Comment: I tried the first piece of code; I noticed that because it was not returning the array I could not get the code to work.
To make it work, I added "return arr". I proceeded to add my array and try to sort/print it.

So, since I can't paste the whole code block, I'll suggest you also try it by adding the following on your first algorithm to test if it works for you.


    return arr

A=[(0,'dog'),(1,'fish'),(0,'cat'),(1,'tiger'),(1,'panther'),(0,'horse')]
sort_binary_key(A)
print(A)

Comment: @DeeKay returning the sorted array shouldn't be necessary for an in-place-algorithm in the first place. Anyhow, my algorithm was only intended as a demonstration of the basic idea, not a copy-paste-solution. It only works with integer-arrays! Should be fairly simple to rewrite though

Comment: Thank you very much. As I stated above I was not looking for a piece of code to rip off, more so trying to comprehend why my code was wrong and how any other code would fit better. As you may realize I am in my very early stages of programming (or the math that comes with it), so I am in an everending quest that demands learning more and more things before comprehending a simple code-block. Your help has been much appreciated.

(Just noticed that you actually state in your original post what data this code works with, maybe this was there before and I did not notice it. In any case, ty!)

Comment: @DeeKay I've added the detail of what data the algorithm works with after you mentioned the test. I completely forgot about pointing that initially. One last point, since you're new here: please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer, if it solved your problem, so it's marked as solved ;)

Comment: thank you for your input once again. I have taken the day to actually wrap my head around the algorithm (and more tutorials) and see how I can actually apply it in my problem. I will make sure to come back to this thread and mark it as solved once I've achieved some progress; promise not to forget :)

Comment: Accepted :), thank you for the time you spent helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm could not work from a much deeper level.
You running an **O(n)** complexity general sorting algorithm. There is no algorithm for **general sorting** with that *average* complexity (if you find one, let me know!). Check [this table of complexities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) of different sorting algorithms.

If your scenario is only with `0` and `1`, and you want all the `0` at the start and `1` at the end (unstable), then it could be done with O(n) 
 (Check [Paul's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803686/1918287) to see how) and your algorithm is utterly different.

---

You can use python list [`sort`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort) and just pass the key:

```
A = [(1,'cat'), (1,'dog'), (0,'giraffe'), (0,'cheetah'),(1,'elephant')]
sorted(A, key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> [(0, 'giraffe'), (0, 'cheetah'), (1, 'cat'), (1, 'dog'), (1, 'elephant')]
```

You can also make it consider secondary key (first name and secondly a number):

```
B = [(1,'cat'), (0,'cat'), (0,'giraffe'), (0,'cheetah'),(1,'elephant')]
sorted(B, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
>>> [(0, 'cat'), (1, 'cat'), (0, 'cheetah'), (1, 'elephant'), (0, 'giraffe')]
```

Python has a [default sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517347/1918287) and in your case, you could simply write:

```
C = [(1,'cat'), (0,'cat'), (0,'giraffe'), (0,'cheetah'),(1,'elephant')]
sorted(C)
>>> [(0, 'cat'), (1, 'cat'), (0, 'cheetah'), (1, 'elephant'), (0, 'giraffe')]
```

Comment: I apologize if I misled you, but the purpose of the exercise is to use the appropriate algorithm, not just the appropriate Python function. I'm just coding/testing in Python, but the purpose and exercise is Algorithm oriented.

Comment: Such an algorithm **can** work. The important detail is that the algorithm needs to sort for a binary trait.