# Python built-in functions time/space complexity

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance, sorting, big-o

For python built-in functions such as:

```
sorted()
min()
max()
```

what are time/space complexities, what algorithms are used?

Is it always advisable to use the built-in functions of python?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517347/3768871 for `sorted`

Comment: Yes, it is advisable to use the built-in functions of python. They are debugged, documented, and optimised. Many are written in C, all ae written by very good coders.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, sorted is timsort (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1517347/3768871)) which is O(n log(n)) and a [stable sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important). `max` and `min` will run in Θ(n). But, if you want to find both of them in a solution, you can find them using 3n/2 comparison instead of 2n. (Although in general they are in O(n)). To know more about the method see [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52663/64229).