# What's the algorithm behind sort() in python before TimSort?

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.x

TimSort came into existence in year 2002 and Python has been using TimSort for in built sort function from version  Python 2.3. But What about the earlier versions?

Comment: in continuation with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this Python bug tracker entry](https://bugs.python.org/issue587076), it looks like the previous implementation was a [samplesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samplesort).

It was originally proposed as a second means of sorting, but by the time it was accepted and merged, they decided to replace samplesort completely.

Comment: Elsewhere, Tim Peters calls it the original algorithm a "[highly tuned samplesort
hybrid](https://bugs.python.org/file4451/timsort.txt)."

Comment: What is it's detailed time complexity?

Comment: @RaghavPuri: The Wikipedia article provides that information on samplesort. In practice, the reasons for choosing TimSort are provided in that Python bug tracker entry; it's stable, and it runs *much* faster when the input data is already partially sorted (making it ideal for Python, with one sort to rule them all, so doing `sortedlist1 += sortedlist2`, then `sortedlist1.sort()`, isn't doing full `O(n log n)` work to reestablish the sort invariant, largely removing the need for optimized "merge sorted sequences better than re-sorting" code). It also does slightly fewer comparisons.