# Time complexity in sort function

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

In python we use the sort function (example if we have a list-a then we use a.sort() to sort that list). But how to know that the sort function uses which type of sort (bubble,selection,insertion,etc).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `.sort` python function uses the [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) algotithm. You can learn more in this post --> [About Python's built in sort() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method)

Comment: i was solving a question in which expected time complexity was O(N) and i used .sort function. According to Timsort the time complexity is O(n logn). So if i used the .sort function ( as it uses Timsort function the time complexity is nlogn ) it should not have accepted my solution but it did accept

Comment: @Soham No, if you see at the right side of the wikipedia timsort page, in the Best-Case performance the time complexity is O(n) and not O(n log n).