# Time Complexity when processing output

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm struggling to figure out what the time complexity for this code would be.

```
def under_ten(input_list : List[int]) -> List[int]:
    res = []
    for i in input_list:
        if i < 10:
            res.append(i)

    res.sort()
    return res
```

Since the loop iterates over every element of n, I think the best case should be `O(n)`. What I'm not sure about is how sorting the result list affects the time complexity of the entire function. Is the worst case `O(nlogn)` (all numbers in n are under 10, so the result list is the same size as the input list)? And what would be the average case?

EDIT: Changed input name from n to input_list and added type hints, sorry if that caused some confusion (added type hints as well).

Comment: Which sorting algorithm do you use?

Comment: If `n` is a list, you should not be writing `O(n)`.

Comment: Replace the call to `sort` by a simple counting sort, and you get `O(input_list.length)` worst-case complexity. BTW, it's unclear what you mean by `n` in `O(n)` since you haven't defined `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first observation is correct that iterating the input collection would be an `O(N)` operation, where `N` here is the length of the array called `n`.  The running time of the sort operation at the end would depend on how large the `res` array is.  In the worst case scenario, every number in `n` would be less than 10, and therefore would end up in `res`.  The internal algorithm Python would be using for `sort()` would likely be either quicksort or mergesort (q.v. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method)).  Both of these algorithms use a divide-and-conquer approach which run in `O(N*lgN)`.  So, in the worst case, your `under_ten()` function would run in `O(N*lgN)`.

Comment: OP tricked you with weird variable names. n is an iterator or container. Time complexity would depend on N=len(n) But of course you are correct that it would be O(N log N) because of the sort.

Comment: I'll note that this function could be re-written in O(N*N) by prepending to res, or it could be re-written in O(N) using a non-comparison-based sort, thanks to the limited range of values.

Comment: The behavior of Quicksort is well-known to be O(N²), whatever the pivot selection strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Let N be the length of the list and K the number of elements smaller than 10.

The complexity is O(N + K log K), assuming that append is done in amortized constant time.

In the worst case, K=N, hence O(N Log N), provided the sort truly has a worst case O(N Log N). Otherwise, it could be O(N²).

Comment: The sort is _not_ done on 10 elements.  It is done on an array which only contains elements _less than 10_ .

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: ouch, n is a list ! Sorry.