# How can I re-order the values of a dictionary in python?

Tags: dictionary, set, python-2.7

I'm attempting to reorder the values of a particular key in a python dictionary.

For instance, if a I have dictionary {'a':"hello","hey","hi"}

When i print the values of 'a', how could I change the order of "hello", "hey", or "hi"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rephrase this: the value of your key 'a' in your dictionary is a **list** containing 3 string-objects.

```
dict = { 'a': [ "hello", "hey", "hi" ] }
```

this being the case, you can sort the list [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: Thank you, although, I am attempted to sort by the order that they were added to the dictionary, is this still possible with sort()?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some code, but I think a list might maintain the chronological order automatically (just a guess).