# Sorting list of string with specific locale in python

Tags: python, locale, ctypes, glibc

I work on an application that uses texts from different languages, so, for viewing or reporting purposes, some texts (strings) need to be sorted in a specific language.

Currently I have a workaround messing with the global locale settings, which is bad, and I don't want to put it in production:

```
default_locale = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE)

def sort_strings(strings, locale_=None):
    if locale_ is None:
        return sorted(strings)

    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, locale_)
    sorted_strings = sorted(strings, cmp=locale.strcoll)
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, default_locale)

    return sorted_strings
```

The official python locale documentation explicitly says that saving and restoring is a bad idea, but does not give any suggestions: http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glibc does support a locale API with an explicit state. Here's a quick wrapper for that API made with ctypes.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8
import ctypes


class Locale(object):
    def __init__(self, locale):
        LC_ALL_MASK = 8127
        # LC_COLLATE_MASK = 8
        self.libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
        self.ctx = self.libc.newlocale(LC_ALL_MASK, locale, 0)



    def strxfrm(self, src, iteration=1):
        size = 3 * iteration * len(src)
        dest =  ctypes.create_string_buffer('\000' * size)
        n = self.libc.strxfrm_l(dest, src, size,  self.ctx)
        if n < size:
            return dest.value
        elif iteration<=4:
            return self.strxfrm(src, iteration+1)
        else:
            raise Exception('max number of iterations trying to increase dest reached')


    def __del__(self):
        self.libc.freelocale(self.ctx)
```

and a short test

```
locale1 = Locale('C')
locale2 = Locale('mk_MK.UTF-8')

a_list = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'ј', 'ќ', 'џ', 'ш']
import random
random.shuffle(a_list)

assert sorted(a_list, key=locale1.strxfrm) == ['а', 'б', 'в', 'ш', 'ј', 'ќ', 'џ']
assert sorted(a_list, key=locale2.strxfrm) == ['а', 'б', 'в', 'ј', 'ќ', 'џ', 'ш']
```

what's left to do is implement all the locale functions, support for python unicode strings (with wchar* functions I guess), and automatically import the include file definitions or something

Answer (score 10):

You could use a ***[PyICU](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU)'s*** collator to avoid changing global settings:

```
import icu # PyICU

def sorted_strings(strings, locale=None):
    if locale is None:
       return sorted(strings)
    collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(locale))
    return sorted(strings, key=collator.getSortKey)
```

Example:

```
>>> L = [u'sandwiches', u'angel delight', u'custard', u'éclairs', u'glühwein']
>>> sorted_strings(L)
['angel delight', 'custard', 'glühwein', 'sandwiches', 'éclairs']
>>> sorted_strings(L, 'en_US')
['angel delight', 'custard', 'éclairs', 'glühwein', 'sandwiches']
```

*Disadvantage:* dependency on [PyICU library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU); the behavior is slightly different from `locale.strcoll`.

---

I don't know how to get `locale.strxfrm` function given a locale name without changing it globally. As a *hack* you could *run your function in a different child process*:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
# ...
pool.apply(locale_aware_sort, [strings, loc])
```

*Disadvantage:* might be slow, resource hungry

---

Using ordinary `threading.Lock` won't work unless you can control every place where locale aware functions (they are not limited to `locale` module e.g., `re`) could be called from multiple threads.

Answer (score 6):

The `ctypes` solution is fine, but if anyone in the future would like just to modify your original solution, here is a way how to do so:

Temporary changes of global settings can safely be accomplished with a context manager.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import locale

@contextmanager
def changedlocale(newone):
    old_locale = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE)
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, newone)
        yield locale.strcoll
    finally:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, old_locale)

def sort_strings(strings, locale_=None):
    if locale_ is None:
        return sorted(strings)

    with changedlocale(locale_) as strcoll:
        return sorted(strings, cmp=strcoll)

    return sorted_strings
```

This ensures a clean restoration of the original locale - as long as you don't use threading.