# Locale aware sorting of strings in Plone

Tags: python, sorting, plone, locale

---

The standard approach for storing a Plone catalog query using

```
result = catalog(..., sort_on='sortable_title')
```

is not very useful in reality since the sorting rules differ by country and language.

This is some build-in functionality for sorting a list of strings (or objects) for a
given locale?

The standard trick for switching the locale of Python temporarily is not suitable since it is not thread-safe.

Any options?

Comment: Does [Sorting list of string with specific locale in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11121636) help?

Comment: Switching locales inside a multi-threaded application is not appropriate as you should know.

Comment: That's why I linked to that question, it provides context-specific locales. No switching.