# How to correctly sort accented letters in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, locale

I have to no avail, tried to get the Norwegian letters to be sorted in correct order.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'no_no')
sorted(list('æøå')) # string is already in correct alphabetical order
```

only to get this:

```
['å', 'æ', 'ø']
```

What am I missing? (using Python 3.6.5)

Comment: So, to sort according to the current locale, taking language-specific rules into account (cmp_to_key is a helper function from functools),  try  `sorted(list, key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121636/sorting-list-of-string-with-specific-locale-in-python

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that Python uses the unicode values in order to sort characters.

```
ord('å') # = 229
ord('æ') # = 230
ord('ø') # = 248
```

So in that sense python correctly orders the values.