# sort Persian strings for python

Tags: python, persian

I want to use sort function of python but it does not work well.

```
sorted( ['ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ح', 'س', 'ص', 'ف', 'ک', 'ک', 'ک', 'م', 'م']) = 
 ['ا', 'ب', 'ح', 'س', 'ص', 'ف', 'م', 'م', 'پ', 'ک', 'ک', 'ک']
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about "does not work well"? What is the error? What is the expected output?

Comment: in persian character order پ is after ب  but here is false. the problem is it use arabic order  that is written in unicode.

Comment: You will probably need to set a LOCALE to sort stuff. Try the suggestions here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121636/sorting-list-of-string-with-specific-locale-in-python

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try using [PyICU](https://pypi.org/project/PyICU):

```
import icu
collator = icu.Collator.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('fa_IR.UTF-8'))
print ([i for i in sorted(['ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ح', 'س', 'ص', 'ف', 'ک', 'ک', 'ک', 'م', 'م'], key=collator.getSortKey)])
```

Comment: my code worked with icu.Collator.createInstance instead of icu.Collator.Collator.createInstance.

Answer (score 2):

No, it works well... I believe `sorted` sorts characters based on their associated unicode value. The following is the unicode character for each character:

```
ا : \u0627
ب : \u0628
ح : \u062d
س : \u0633
ص : \u0635
ف : \u0641
م : \u0645
پ : \u067e
ک : \u06a9
```

As you can see, the unicode of `پ` is `\u067e` while the unicode of `ب` is `\u0628`. And the reason for that is the `ب` is also an Arabic character the same as `ا` , `ح`, `س`, `ص`, `ف`, and `م`. While `پ` and `ک` are not.