# Ascending order , in list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort a list of strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

I wrote a program, whose output is a list, the problem is that I can't make the program to get the list in ascending order, so now I want to find a method to sort a list in ascending order, for any lenght , may you help me?
These is my code:

```
import math
n=int(input())
notPrimes=[]
primes=[]
numbers=list(range(0,n))
numbers.remove(1)
numbers.remove(0)
for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n)+1)):
   for j in numbers:
    if j%i==0:
        notPrimes.append(j)
    if j in numbers:
        numbers.remove(j)
#notPrimes is the list I have to sort
```

These is my code, and I need that list in ascending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
numbers = sorted(numbers)
```

If you want descending order:

```
numbers = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
```