# How to get unique sorted list in one statement?

Tags: python

The return value of sort() is None so the following code doesn't work:

```
def sorted_unique_items(a):
   return list(set(a)).sort()
```

Any idea for better solution?

Comment: This answer might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sorted(set(a))
```

and you can omit the `list()` call entirely.

Comment: Thank you for this elegant answer

Answer (score 1):

Its simple Just use the `sorted()` method :

```
data = [10,5,46,4]
sorted_data = sorted(data)
print "Sorted Data ::::",sorted_data
```

Comment: This doesn't remove duplicate items from `data`.

Comment: if you want omit the duplicate than use the set 
    sorted_data = sorted(set(data))

Comment: Thanks @ Burhan Khalid to Complete the Ans.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution is only work for hashable type like string,integer and tuple but it not work for unhashable type like list.

for example if you have a list `data= [[2],[1],[2],[4]]`

for unhashable type best solution is :

```
from itertools import izip, islice

values= [[2],[1],[2],[4]]

def sort_unique_unhashable(values):

    values = sorted(values)
    if not values:
        return []
    consecutive_pairs = izip(values, islice(values, 1, len(values)))
    result = [a for (a, b) in consecutive_pairs if a != b]
    result.append(values[-1])
    return result
print sort_unique_unhashable(values)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is Two options:

```
a = [2,34,55,1,22,11,22,55,1]

#First option using sorted and set. 
sorted(set(a))

#second option using list and set.
list(set(a))
```