# Python - arranging words in alphabetical order

Tags: python, list, range, alphabetical

The program must print the name which is alphabetically the last one out of 8 elements.
The names/words can be inputted in any way through code.
I think I should be using lists and `in range()` here. I had an idea of comparing the first/second/third/... letter of the input name with the letters of the previous one and then putting it at the end of the list or in front of the previous one (depending on the comparison), and then repeating that for the next name. At the end the program would print the last member of the list.

Comment: Is this an exercise that you have to do in a particular way, or can you just use `sort` or `max` as recommended in the answers already given?

Comment: I don't want to write a full answer right now, but you should keep in mind that the answers recommending `max` and `sort` won't necessarily handle capitalization correctly, since they sort by [the numeric value of a character](http://www.asciitable.com/) (so `A` < `B`, but `a` > `B`).

Comment: For that you can always use upper or lower

Comment: Here's an example of how to correctly sort alphabetically using a particular locale's settings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36156/212555

Answer (score 9):

Python's string comparisons are lexical by default, so you should be able to call `max` and get away with it:

```
In [15]: sentence
Out[15]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
In [16]: max(sentence)
Out[16]: 'this'
```

Of course, if you want to do this manually:

```
In [16]: sentence
Out[16]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']

In [17]: answer = ''

In [18]: for word in sentence:
   ....:     if word > answer:
   ....:         answer = word
   ....:         

In [19]: print answer
this
```

Or you can sort your sentence:

```
In [20]: sentence
Out[20]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']

In [21]: sorted(sentence)[-1]
Out[21]: 'this'
```

Or, sort it reversed:

```
In [25]: sentence
Out[25]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']

In [26]: sorted(sentence, reverse=True)[0]
Out[26]: 'this'
```

But if you want to fully manual (which is so painful):

```
def compare(s1, s2):
    for i,j in zip(s1, s2):
        if ord(i)<ord(j):
            return -1
        elif ord(i)>ord(j):
            return 1
    if len(s1)<len(s2):
        return -1
    elif len(s1)>len(s2):
        return 1
    else return 0

answer = sentence[0]
for word in sentence[1:]:
    if compare(answer, word) == -1:
        answer = word

# answer now contains the biggest word in your sentence
```

If you want this to be agnostic of capitalization, be sure to call `str.lower()` on your `word`s first:

```
sentence = [word.lower() for word in sentence] # do this before running any of the above algorithms
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `sort()` method.

```
strings = ['c', 'b', 'a']
strings.sort()
print strings
```

Output will be,

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

In case you want the last, you can use the `max()` method.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in a previous answer, string comparisons are lexical by default, so `min()` and `max()` can be used.  To handle both upper- and lower-cased words, one can specify `key=str.lower`.  For example:

```
s=['This', 'used', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'Whopping', 'Great', 'sentence']
print min(s), min(s, key=str.lower)
# Great a

print max(s), max(s, key=str.lower)
# used Whopping
```

Comment: +1. Out of all of the answers, this is the most concise, and it directly answers the OP's question and explains why it works. However, you might want to add some mention of `locale.collate` if you want to handle mixed-case words with non-ASCII letters.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a mix of capitalized words and lowercase words you could do this:

```
from string import capwords     

words = ['bear', 'Apple', 'Zebra','horse']

words.sort(key = lambda k : k.lower())

answer = words[-1]
```

Result:

```
>>> answer
'Zebra'
>>> words
['Apple', 'bear', 'horse', 'Zebra']
```

Comment: Why would you use `string.capwords(s)` instead of just `s.lower()` or `s.upper()`?

Comment: @abarnert, no real reason. I see that advantage of `s.lower()` and `s.upper()` is that you do not need import any module (`string`), do you know any other advantages?

Comment: Well, comparing `s.lower()` is the paradigmatic way to do case-insensitive (ASCII) comparisons; using a function that's so little-known that they chose not to add it as a `str` method means that people will have to think about the code instead of immediately recognizing what it does (and automated refactoring tools won't recognize it at all). You've heard of "TOOWTDI", right? There are also minor advantages—`lower` is also more likely to be optimized on different Python implementations, it's easier to read (one word that tells you what it does instead of two, one of which is irrelevant), etc.

Answer (score 1):

This would be how I would do it.

1. **Define the string:** For arguments sake let us say that the string is already predefined.

   ```
   sentence = "This is the sentence that I need sorted"
   ```
2. **Use the `split()` method:** The `split()` method returns a list of "words" from the `sentence` string. I use the term "word" here loosely as the method has no conception of "word", it merely separates the `sentence` string into a list by parsing it for characters delimited by whitespace and outputs these characters as discrete items in a list. This list is not yet alphabetically ordered.

   ```
   split_sentence = sentence.split()
   ```
3. **Use the `sorted` function:** The sorted function returns an alphabetically ordered version of the `split_sentence` list.

   ```
    sorted_sentence = sorted(split_sentence)
   ```
4. **Print the last element in the list:**

   ```
   print(sorted_sentence[-1])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In python the method sort() sorts all strings alphabetically so you can use that function.

You can make a list of all your words and then :

```
  listName.sort()
```

This would result a alphabetically sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following:

```
max(sentence.lower().split())
```