# sort a .txt file after splitting the file to lines in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, sorting

I got stuck while learning on-line Python 3 (Coursera. Love them).

I have a `.txt` file with several lines. each line has several words in it. I need to split the files to line, I'm already using:

```
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line.split()
```

Now I need to sort the words from the entire file (from all the lines) Alphabetically, but I get are strings in the list (that I already created named `lst`). So I get the entire strings sorted alphabetically but couldn't sort the words inside them sorted.

I see that it looks like the question already been asked, but it's a little bit different. Let's take this text for example :

```
"In the beginning of creation of the heavens and the earth
Now the earth was astonishingly empty and darkness was"
```

What I need is to sort the entire list of words alphabetically (after trimming same words), so the result should be `['In', 'Now', 'and', 'astonishingly', 'beginning']` and so on.

I really tried to find in myself and I'm taking this course seriously. I need some help here.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Usually you should include some example data and your attempt to solve the problem.  Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Create an empty list `all_words = []` at the top, and for each `line`, you can `all_words.extend(line.rstrip().split())` and `all_words.sort()` at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - arranging words in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809542/python-arranging-words-in-alphabetical-order)

Comment: No need for all that iteration because `str.split()` without any arguments splits on *any* whitespace and it treats consecutive whitespace as single delimiter.  So `"a b\t\tc\nd e     f\n \ng".split()` returns `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']`.  So just do `words = fh.read().split()` and then `words.sort()`.

Comment: Do you want unique words or all words?  Does case matter?  Is `"Now"` the same as `"now"`?  What about `"James"` and `"james"`?  Does your text include punctuation that you need to ignore?  In `"Python 3"` are both `"Python"` and `"3"` words?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a list of all unique words in the file, and assuming there is no punctuation or other non-word content

```
word_list = sorted({ w for line in fh for w in line.strip().split() })
```

will do it

if you want the words sorted on a line by line basis

```
words = [ sorted(set(line.strip().split())) for line in fh ]
```

will do that

Comment: `line.strip().split()` will always equal `line.split()`.  But why not even more directly with `word_list = sorted(fh.read().split())`?

Comment: Thank you! It works though we didn't work on the sorted() func but a little bit different. I appreciate your time and help. Thanks