# Python internal sort method

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, big-o

Does anyone know what type of sort Python uses internally for list.sort()? Or that it at least guarantees O(n*log(n))? The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) don't say much. I was wondering after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python uses [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), a new algorithm developed by Tim Peters.

It is a O(NlogN) sorting algorithm, yes, both for the worst and average cases. In ideal situations it improves to O(N). See the [Python Wiki Time Complexity page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) and the Wikipedia article I linked you to.

Note that the algorithm has proven quite popular and it has been added to Java SE 7, Android, and GNU Octave as well.