# Complexity of Python Sort Method

Tags: python, time-complexity

If I have to sort some list, say a, using the `sort method` in Python such as below..

```
a=[3,7,1,0,2,8]
a.sort()
print a
```

What are the `worst, average and best cases` of such programs in case of sorting ? And what complexities would they have in each ? What sorting technique does python use in this ?

Comment: Also see [About python's built in sort() method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1517347) and [Python internal sort method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21558903)

Comment: This question is more specific.

Comment: Not really; the method and complexity are named in the specific duplicate, and you can get more info still from the links provided.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python uses [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which was named after Tim Peters, the Python developer who invented it. The Wikipedia page has complexity information:

```
Worst case performance  O(nlogn)
Best case performance   O(n)
Average case performance    O(nlogn)
Worst case space complexity O(n)
```

Comment: `Cpython` (and probably other implementations) use Timsort -- The only requirements in the language reference are that the sorting method is stable.  I think maybe one or two implementations might use `mergesort` which pretty much the same complexity except for best-case performance.

Comment: There’s a [document](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/listsort.txt) in the source tree that describes how timsort works and performs in detail.

Comment: The C code behind the built-in sort function. http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c?revision=69227&view=markup

Comment: It's worth understanding that Timsort's best case is the whole point, because its best cases aren't just some random subset of the space, they include most things that you'd reasonably consider "mostly already sorted".

Comment: @asmeurer I have added a part in the question. Please help me with that.

Comment: @h8pathak this question has been closed, so if you have any further questions please open a new question.