# How to sort a list with user defined condition in python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python.I want to sort a list with certain condition.
ex:

I am getting the environment details and storing them as list as below.
    `ls = ['qa','uat','prod','dev']`
They can be any order.
    `ls = ['uat','qa','dev','prod']`

But the result list should be:

```
rls = ['prod','qa','uat','dev']
```

Comment: What is the condition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list of strings in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom comparator function, as described in https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter.

Or you can use a key function (by passing the `key` keyword argument to list.sort) to transform the value being sorted to a different one:

```py
>>> ls = ['qa','uat','prod','dev']
>>> ls.sort(key=lambda x: (1,x) if x=='dev' else (0,x))
>>> ls
['prod', 'qa', 'uat', 'dev']
>>>
```

or do the same thing with a function:

```
>>> def my_key_func(x):
...     if x=='dev':
...         return (1,x)
...     else:
...         return (0,x)
...
>>> ls.sort(key=my_key_func)
>>> ls
['prod', 'qa', 'uat', 'dev']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer, it solved my problem. As i am new to python can you please explain to me how this sort worked.

Comment: `my_key_func` will transform strings to tuples: `[(0,'qa'), (0,'uat'), (0,'prod'), (1,'dev')]`, such that when sorting using natural order, first they will be compared by the first numeric element, and if that is equal, they will be compared by the second element, which is a string, and strings are naturally sorted alphabetically. `'dev'` goes to the end of list because it has an higher first numeric element.

Comment: if you want to know more, read https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can define custom lambda functions and send them as key argument to the sorted function in python as :

sorted(list,key = lambdafn)

this lambda fn should have boolean return value, will not work otherwise.

finally got hold of the documentation, see more here :
https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

PS  : Sorry about poor answer style,first ever answer in SO