# How can i sort output of json in python

Tags: python, json

how can i output the title alphabetically? i want it to print 'entertainment' then 'information'.

note: this is just a sample. the json file i am working with has many more titles

```html
>>> import json

>>> field = json.loads('{"js":[{"id":"1","title":"information","number":"1","alias":"information"},{"id":"2","title":"entertainments","number":"2","alias":"entertainments"}],"text":""}')

>>> for data in field['js']:
...     print data['title']
... 

information
entertainments
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list of strings in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: didnt work, but will try again

Comment: google definitely works, I can assure you.

Comment: not referring to google, but the method in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the list using a key:

```
field['js'].sort(key=lambda k: k['title'])
```

For more info, see [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72899/584846)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
>>> for data in sorted(field['js']):
...   print data['title']
... 
entertainments
information
```