# Python - Sorting a list of strings (names and scores) from highest to lowest

Tags: python, string, list, numbers, integer

Lets say I had this list of names and scores:

```
scores_list = ["Username1,9,5,6", "Username2,7,6,8", "Username3,10,10,7"]
```

Each value in the list is formatted as -Name-Score1-Score2-Score3-

How would I sort this list so that the user with the highest score from their past 3 results is first all the way down to the lowest score last.

So, in this case, I want it would be ordered like this

```
("Username3,10,10,7", "Username1,9,6,5", "Username2,8,7,6")
```

as 10 is the higest, then 9, then 8.

So, essentially, I need the three scores to be put in order from higest to lowest, Then the highest score from each value in the list to be ordered from highest to lowest too.

Maybe I need to give each value in the list its own index so it's a 2d list?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list of strings in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: how did you manage to get such a terrible structure, are you reading this from a file?

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to split up each entry and sort the scores numerically. The resulting list can then be recombined to create the updated `scores_list` as follows:

```
scores_list = ["Username1,9,5,6", "Username2,7,6,8", "Username3,10,10,7"]
output = []

for entry in scores_list:
    values = entry.split(',')
    output.append([values[0], sorted([int(x) for x in values[1:]], reverse=True)])

scores_list = ['{},{}'.format(entry[0], ','.join(str(x) for x in entry[1])) for entry in sorted(output, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]
print scores_list
```

This would display the following:

```
['Username3,10,10,7', 'Username1,9,6,5', 'Username2,8,7,6']
```

Comment: Why do you want to do all this when they can be done using normal `key` attribute

Comment: As the strings themselves also need to be sorted, specifically Username1 and Username2 are in the incorrect order.

Comment: okay got it :). If that's what OP want then my answer is wrong :P

Answer (score 0):

Using `sorted or .sort method` and [**key**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes) attribute of sort

**Code:**

```
scores_list = ["Username1,920,5,6", "Username2,10,11,8", "Username3,10,10,7"]
def transform(lst):
    return map(int, lst.split(",")[1:])
print sorted(scores_list, key= transform ,reverse=True)
```

**Output:**

```
['Username3,10,10,7', 'Username1,9,5,6', 'Username2,7,6,8']
```

**Notes:**

- We are calling `tranform` function on the key attribute on sorted
- In transform function we slipt at `,` and transform them to integer list and give it to key

Answer (score 0):

First, user a function to convert each element like `Username1,9,5,6` to a list, like `["Username1",9,5,6]`. At the same time, sort the three scores, the final form of each element is like `["Username1",9,6,5]`, then sort the transferred data. Finally, join elements of lists of the sorted list

```
scores_list = ["Username1,9,5,6", "Username2,7,6,8", "Username3,10,10,7"]
def transfer(x):
    items = x.split(",")
    result = [items[0]] + sorted(map(int,items[1:]), reverse = True)
    return result

transfered = map(transfer,scores_list)
transfered.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse = True)

result = [",".join(map(str,x)) for x in transfered]
print result

>>>output:
['Username3,10,10,7', 'Username1,9,6,5', 'Username2,8,7,6']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading this from a file you would be much better using the csv module to parse so the data:

```
from csv import reader
with open("your_file") as f:
      srt = sorted(([row[0]] + sorted(map(int, row[1:]), reverse=1) for row in reader(f)), reverse=1)
      for row in srt:
          print(row)
```

Output:

```
['Username3', 10, 10, 7]
['Username2', 8, 7, 6]
['Username1', 9, 6, 5]
```

If you plan on using the data then having it separated will make life much easier.

When you are finished with the data you can rewrite to file using a `csv.writer`:

```
with open("your_file","w") as out:
      wr = csv.writer(out)
      wr.writerows(srt)
```

Which will give you:

```
Username3,10,10,7
Username2,8,7,6
Username1,9,6,5
```

Comment: That's one way of sorting :P. Now I feel the OP is unclear in saying how to sort it .

Comment: @VigneshKalai, the OP  actually also needs each row sorted too

Comment: Yes everything is implicitly said from his output. So we can't come to a conclusion with out more information from him.