# Sorting list of AB strings based on the whole string

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have the following list:

```
lst = ['AAAAAABB', 'AAAAAABA', 'AAAAAAAB', 'AAAAABAA', 'AAAAABAB', 'AAAAABBA']
```

And I'm getting this:

```
lst = ['AAAAAAAB', 'AAAAAABA', 'AAAAAABB', 'AAAAABAA', 'AAAAABAB', 'AAAAABBA']
```

But I want something like this:

```
lst = ['AAAAAAAB', 'AAAAAABA', 'AAAAABAA', 'AAAAAABB', 'AAAAABAB', 'AAAAABBA']
```

It means, I want to sort my list by Python considering the sequences of A and B in each list item.

Actually, I want that all the combinations with 7*A should appear first. After that should come the combinations with more than one B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: The only difference in the order of the sorted list and your desired order is items at index 2 and 3 are swapped. For 'AAAAABAA', 'AAAAAABB', how do you determine the 'BAA' in the first sequence should appear before 'ABB', when lexicographically shouldn't 'A' appear *before* 'B'?

Comment: Actually, I want that all the combinations with 7*A should apears first. After that come the combinations with more than one B.

Comment: @Miraj50 what is the criteria of the order? why "AAAAABAA" < "AAAAAABB"?

Comment: @DamianLattenero I think because `AAAAABAA` has one `B` while the latter has two.

Comment: mmm it's not enough info... we should wait for @DiegoGuedes-Sobrinho to clarify

Comment: Yes, @DamianLattenero is right! The criteria is the number of B's

Comment: @DiegoGuedes-Sobrinho nice im working in a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I always forget this comment, but it is really important, DO NOT CALL A VARIABLE WITH NAMES AS "list, dict" etc, those name has special meaning for python

Edit: you are sorting by amount of "b"

You can sort the list:

```
import functools

lst = ['AAAAAABB', 'AAAAAABA', 'AAAAAAAB', 'AAAAABAA', 'AAAAABAB', 'AAAAABBA']

def sort_by_b(a,b):
  ab = a.count('B')
  bb =  b.count('B')
  if (ab == bb and a < b) or ab < bb:
    return -1
  elif ab > bb:
    return 1
  else:
    return a == b

print(sorted(lst, key=functools.cmp_to_key(sort_by_b)))
```

as result:

```
['AAAAAAAB', 'AAAAAABA', 'AAAAABAA', 'AAAAAABB', 'AAAAABAB', 'AAAAABBA']
```

Comment: @Miraj50 what is the criteria of the order?

Comment: Isn't the answer supposed to be `lst = ['AAAAAAAB', 'AAAAAABA', 'AAAAABAA', 'AAAAAABB', 'AAAAABAB', 'AAAAABBA']`

Comment: @Miraj50 you were totally right, thank you so much, I corrected the answer. Please considere to read it

Answer (score 2):

I think I get what you are trying to do! Correct me if I am wrong. Basically it depends on `B`, isn't it? The more number of times B appears or closer is a `B` to the starting of a string, further away it appears in the final answer list, isn't it?

So, here is what I do.

- First, I get a list in which the strings has been sorted in the order of the frequency of `B`.
- This is not sufficient, as the order of the strings matter in the original list. For seeing this remove the for loop from my answer and print `lst`, you will clearly see the issue.
- So now I need to `sort`(the normal lexicographic sort) each group of strings which have the same frequency of `B`. I used `groupby` for this. See the uses of [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and sorted each such group and appended them to the final answer.

  ```
  from itertools import groupby

  lst = ['AAAAAABB', 'AAAAAABA', 'AAAAAAAB', 'AAAAABAA', 'AAAAABAB', 'AAAAABBA']
  ans = []
  lst.sort(key=lambda x:x.count('B'))
  for i,j in groupby(lst, lambda x:x.count('B')):
      ans.extend(sorted(list(j)))

  print ans
  ```

Output:

```
['AAAAAAAB', 'AAAAAABA', 'AAAAABAA', 'AAAAAABB', 'AAAAABAB', 'AAAAABBA']
```

Comment: ahahahah we are in the same page, yes, totally right the answer. plus one

Comment: Thank you guys. However, I have edited the post to make more clear. Please, if you could check it now.

Comment: @DiegoGuedes-Sobrinho Good! Try figuring out how this works. Otherwise ask me and I shall explain it to you. Good Question, btw!!

Comment: @Miraj50 damn, I don't know how did you achieve this, could you explain to me?

Comment: @DiegoGuedes-Sobrinho Done.