# Python - Why does .sort() change the original array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

For example:

```
a = [5,3,7,5]

b = a

b.sort()

print a
print b
```

---

```
a = [3,5,5,7]

b = [3,5,5,7]
```

I don't want the programm to change a. How can I avoid this?

PS: Yes i know the question has been asked before, but these questions were asked for C or C#, not Python.

Comment: Use `sorted(arr)` instead

Comment: Use `b=a.copy()`. By using `b=a`, you are creating a reference to initial variable `a`. All the changes in `b` will therefore be reflected in `a`

Comment: @Aran Maybe add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings, it may say strings but same applies to numbers and accepted answers mentions how to not change original array

Comment: @NickA I don't think that tells the OP anything they didn't know. They clearly already know how to sort a list, no? As far as I can tell, the question is why `b = a` doesn't make a copy.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I think it does in that they can use `b = sorted(a)`, instead of `b = a.copy()` followed by sorting, however it is only a suggestion so feel free not to

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't know b = a is just creating a reference and not an independent variable. I'm using import copy + copy.copy(a) now and it works fine.

Comment: @NickA I like your answer even better because as you said, b = a.copy() becomes no longer necessary