# sorting labels in matplotlib scaterplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following code for a scatterplot, and the corresponding plot is shown below:

```
x = ['C9-U2', 'C10-U5', 'C10-U5', 'C11-U1', 'C11-U1']
y = ['J',     'C',      'H',      'J',     'H']
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]

In the plot, I would like to see both axes sorted, ie the x-axis should be [C9, C10, C11] (which is what it is, because I have entered the data in that sequence), and the y-axis should be [C, H, J] (which it is not).

How do I make sure that both axes are sorted?

Comment: Are you asking [how to sort a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings) or [how to sort a list based on values from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)?

Comment: I am asking, how to plot keeping BOTH axes sorted. I can keep any one axis sorted by rearranging the data set, but how to sort both axes together?

Comment: Can you write that clearly in the question. At the moment it reads that you do not care about the x axis. Best describe in detail what exactly the desired outcome would be.

Comment: I have corrected the error in the code, and made the question more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a problem for which there is no good solution at the moment. The axis units are determined as they come from the input. So a solution is to predetermine the categorical order manually by plotting something in the correct order first and then remove it again.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['C9-U2', 'C10-U5', 'C10-U5', 'C11-U1', 'C11-U1']
y = ['J',     'C',      'H',      'J',     'H']

def unitsetter(xunits, yunits, ax=None, sort=True):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    if sort:
        xunits = sorted(xunits)
        yunits = sorted(yunits)
    us = plt.plot(xunits, [yunits[0]]*len(xunits),
                  [xunits[0]]*len(yunits), yunits)
    for u in us:
        u.remove()

unitsetter(x,y)
plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here, `sort` is set to `True`, hence you get alphabetically sorted categories in both axes.

If you have a custom order you want the axis to obey, as is the case here (at least for the x axis) you would need to supply that order to the above function.

```
unitsetter(x, sorted(y), sort=False)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But Michael's solution is simpler.

Comment: Sorry, looks like Michael's solution is not working.

Comment: Your solution works, but I am still trying to figure out what it is doing. Meanwhile, looking for a better solution.

Comment: As said, there is currently no better solution, because the axis units are determined at creation time. An alternative would be not to plot strings, but numbers and then set the ticklabels accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Following 'ImportanceOfBeingErnest ', the code could be shorten to

```
# initial plot to set sorted axis label
us = plt.plot(sorted(x),sorted(y))
[u.remove() for u in us]

# now plot the real thing, sorting not required
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed how your scatterplot is created quite a bit.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# This is your original code.
# x = ['C9-U2', 'C10-U5', 'C10-U5', 'C3-U1', 'C3-U1']
# y = ['J',     'C',      'H',      'J',     'H']
# plt.scatter(x,y)
# plt.show()

ordered_pairs = set([
     ('C9-U2', 'J'),
     ('C10-U5', 'C'),
     ('C10-U5', 'H'),
     ('C3-U1', 'J'),
     ('C3-U1', 'H')
])

x,y = zip(*ordered_pairs)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I turned your data points into a `set` of ordered pairs. This lets us `zip` the set, which is used to pack and unpack arrays with each argument passed. We use the `*` operator to inverse the process. You can read more about `zip` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

When the code is ran, the image shown is the following, which I hope is what you were looking for:

[image: result_of_shown_code]

Comment: While you have sorted the y axis, you have unsorted the x-axis. How to keep both axes sorted? (One error in my code: replace C3 with C11).

Comment: try adding `plt.yticks(ticks=np.arange(0, 3, 1), labels=['J', 'H', 'C'])` right after `plt.scatter(x, y)` (and of course, `import numpy as np`)

Comment: labels=sorted(set(y)) is better. Can you post this as a solution, so that I can accept.

Comment: No, in your solution the labels are now showing as sorted, but the points still remain the same. So this solution is wrong.