# How to sort y axis in desired order in scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I would like to make a scatter plot for the following DataFrame with x-axis topic and y-axis content.

```
In[18]: test=pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
In[19]: test
Out[19]:    topic content
        0    A1       a
        1    A1       b
        2    A2       b
        3    A2       c
        4    A2       e
        5    A3       a
        6    A3       c
        7    A3       d
        8    A4       b
        9    A4       c
```

Below is my current plot:

[image: My current plot]

How can I sort y-axis in a different order? Such as ['b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e'] with 'b' in the bottom?

Comment: Forgot to attach the image?

Comment: I am new to Python and Stack overflow, still struggling with how to post questions in the right way :-)

Comment: No problem at all, asking the right questions in the right way can be hard. Look here for some guidance on this platform https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of the x-axis is not important, you could use pandas `Categorial` and `sort_values()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A1','a'], ['A1','b'], ['A2','b'], ['A2','c'], ['A2','e'], ['A3','a'], ['A3','c'], ['A3','d'], ['A4','b'], ['A4','c']], columns=['topic','content'])

order = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e']
df['content'] = pd.Categorical(df['content'], order)
df.sort_values(by=['content'], inplace=True)

plt.scatter(df['topic'], df['content'])
```

[image]

**Edit** 
Another solution could be replacing each value of `content` with an integener, `df['content'] = [order.index(x) for x in df['content']]` and set the `yticks`:

```
order = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e']
df = pd.DataFrame([['A1','a'], ['A1','b'], ['A2','b'], ['A2','c'], ['A2','e'], ['A3','a'], ['A3','c'], ['A3','d'], ['A4','b'], ['A4','c']], columns=['topic','content'])

df['content'] = [order.index(x) for x in df['content']]

plt.yticks(range(len(order)), order)
plt.scatter(df['topic'], df['content'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! What if I also want x-axis in the order of A1, A2, A3, A4?

Comment: There is no optimal solution (see. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191411/sorting-labels-in-matplotlib-scaterplot), but maybe you could use a workarourn with integers, see my edit.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. :-)