# Python 3 strings in alphabetical order?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I got this assignment for school. The task is: which of the componist comes first in alphabetical order using Python 3. I tried to look up online but couldn't find anything, would appreciate some help. :)

Componists: 'Berlioz', 'Borodin', 'Brian', 'Bartok', 'Bellini', 'Buxtehude', 'Bernstein'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You can use comparison operators to check for the alphabetical order in strings, too:
`'Berlioz' < 'Borodin'`will return `True`, while `'Berlioz' > 'Borodin'`will return `False`

Since the list`.sort()` method uses comparison of the list's components, it is as simple as this:

```
composers = ['Berlioz', 'Borodin', 'Brian', 'Bartok', 'Bellini', 'Buxtehude', 'Berns
tein']
composers.sort()
print(composers)
```

Comment: [Hasan Bhagat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773324/13726558) beat me by a few seconds ;-) The only difference is that his answer creates a new list, while mine does in-place sorting.

Answer (score -1):

If you store the names of the componist in a list and use the `sorted` function, you can get your sorted list

```
componist=list(['Berlioz', 'Borodin', 'Brian', 'Bartok', 'Bellini', 'Buxtehude', 'Bernstein'])
sorted_componist=sorted(componist)
print(sorted_componist)
```

This prints
['Bartok', 'Bellini', 'Berlioz', 'Bernstein', 'Borodin', 'Brian', 'Buxtehude']